# Problem with command-line registeration with PyPI in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, pypi

When I type `c:\python32\python.exe setup.py register` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> I get the following:

```
running register
running check 
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
 1. use your existing login,
 2. register as a new user,
 3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or 
 4. quit
Your selection [default 1]:
```

So i type `1` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and I get:

```
Please choose one of the four options!
```

Why is this happening? It doesn't care what I type. It's always the same result.

**Update:** I tried reinstalling the 32 bit version and reinstalling for the current user but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `.pypirc` file with my username and password in my home folder. That is, `C:\Users\*****`.

```
[distutils] 
index-servers = pypi 

[pypi] 
username: *****
password: *****
```

I was then able to register and upload my module.

**Note:** This is a *workaround*.